# Android Sharing Intent

Tags: android-intent, titanium, share, appcelerator-mobile

Is there any way I can add/list my app with other apps like facebook, gmail, whatsapp and viber in sharing intent on android .? here is the sample image[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't how this would be done using Titanium, but in the conventional way (using Eclipse), this is how I do it in one of my apps:

**CODE:** In your manifest XML file, add the  tag as shown below. This is to be done for an `Activity` that will handle data shared by the user. For example, if my `Activity` is named **`Composer`**, then the structure would be:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Composer"
    android:exported="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

EXPLANATION OF THE CODE:

The key here are the `data` tags nested under the `<intent-filter>`. If I want my app listed when the user shares web links, the `"text/plain"` comes into play. When I want my app to handle Images shared from, say, the Gallery app, the `"image/jpeg"` and the `"image/png"` entries come into play (*depending on the image file extension*). As, however, indicated by the attached screenshot in the OP, if you only need to get your app listed in browsers when sharing web links, then the `<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />` will do it for you.

Again, I do not know if the code above works as-is in Titanium. I have never used it nor have read up on it. You *may have to tweak* it a bit if there is a difference in how this is done when using Titanium.